# Do I need to keep update for microsoft powerpoint 2010?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, microsoft-office-2010, software-update

I was cleaning up my windows 10 pc today using IOBit Uninstaller because I had installed a lot of junk. After uninstalling everything I know about I found a lot of `Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2956076) 64-Bit Edition` and a lot of `Update for Microsoft Outlook Social Connector 2010 (KB2553308) 64-Bit Edition`.

I use Office 2010. So is it okay to uninstall these things or do I have to leave them to have the latest office?

Most of them are about 145.49 MB and I have 60 of these which is equal to 8.52 GB. That is a lot so I really want to uninstall these but I don't know if I should.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 2010 still receives security updates for a little while longer (I saw April 2021 updates).

Power Point can be susceptible to links in slides to dubious sites and locations.

So **Yes**, you should keep the Security Updates and not attempt to uninstall them.

You should make arrangements fairly soon to upgrade Office to a newer version with better security.

Comment: Ok... I will keep the security updates. What about the plan update. These ones: `Update for Microsoft Outlook Social Connector 2010 (KB2553308) 64-Bit Edition`

Comment: I suggest keeping all updates for Office. You get these for newer versions as well.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I will keep them all!

Comment: @AlphaMirage - Determine what issues KB2553308 addresses and determine if you want them installed.  However, they were installed, due to your Windows Update being configured to install Office updates or by an Administrator for a specific reason.

Answer (score 3):

Since the
[End of support for Office 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/end-of-support-for-office-2010-3a3e45de-51ac-4944-b2ba-c2e415432789):

> - Microsoft will no longer provide technical support, bug fixes, or security fixes for Office 2010 vulnerabilities which may be
>   subsequently reported or discovered. This includes security updates
>   which can help protect your PC from harmful viruses, spyware, and
>   other malicious software.
> - **You'll no longer receive Office 2010 software updates from Microsoft Update**.

Therefore any update that you uninstall could possible no longer be redone,
since Windows Update may no longer support Office 2010.

Taking this into account, I do not counsel removing any of these updates.
(Actually I would rather recommend upgrading to a later and supported Office version.)

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I will accept the other answer as they answer first but thanks!